# How do I update textures in the viewport from the textures properties?

Tags: texturing, uv, 3d-view

So when I set my texture up with UV and change a value such as Blue on the texture properties, my texture stays the same. I looked in the UV Editor and my texture is the same, is there a way to update my UV Editor Image live by changing a property in the texture properties area?

EX: Change blue in the texture area and the UV texture turns less blue than before

Comment: There are many unclear details in your question. What render engine do you use? What is that "texture properties / area" where you change "value to blue"? Consider adding more info, screenshots and possibly a .blend file

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As you can see, when you change the parameters of the texture's colors, the texture doesn't change: it changes the way the texture is rendered: in the properties window you have the preview tab for monitoring the process. Another way is to choose the "Rendered" viewport shading in the header of the 3D Window.